# desktop icon not displaying when publishing VB.net program with inno

Tags: inno-setup

What to change so that this part of code displays icon in desktop?

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: The icon will be created just when the `desktopicon` task is selected. Did you met this criteria when testing ?

Comment: Where and how do I select the desktopicon?

Comment: You have a `[Tasks]` and maybe also the `[Components]` sections in your script. There is the answer for this. Either you can have a task connected to a certain component, or as a standalone task check box. Or if you would like to create that icon always (not only conditionally), remove the `Tasks: desktopicon` tail of your second `[Icons]` entry.